# circle overflowing the container

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to make the effect on the image attached. A circle overflowing the container with *CSS* border-radius. It's almost there but not yet right.

[image: circle overflowing the container]

This code is the nearest I can get it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.bg-border-radius {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
  background-color: #0080C1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-border-radius"></div>
```

How can I get it closer to what's on the image with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `<div>` inside another, let's call it "wrapper"

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bg-border-radius"></div>
</div>

.wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now you can arange the circle as you like, with a bigger width than 100%. To make the circle responsive, set `border-radius: 50%`, `height: auto;` and `padding-top: 150%;` <--same as `width`. If you move the circle to `margin-top: -120%;` and `margin-left: -25%;` you'll get something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qcfo5688/

Answer (score 1):

Increase the height and use a negative top-margin:

```
.bg-border-radius {
  margin-top: -200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
  background-color: #0080C1;
}
```

Comment: almost but just like the image i dont want the curves to go all the way up.

Comment: you can make it wider and add a negative left margin like http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/XbPeJB

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction). In the following example, I used a path element with an [arc command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) :

```css
svg { width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50">
  <path fill="#0081C2" d="M0 0 H100 V10 A85 85 1 0 1 0 10z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably have to do a specific width, since you'll need to give it a negative margin on the left to achieve the effect. Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/kLm6a7ym/

```
.bg-border-radius {
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -110px;
  width: 1385px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
  background-color: #0080C1;
}
```

Comment: The left side looks great but can it not be done on both sides?